# How to continue processing css files after the css-loader of vue-cli？

Tags: vue.js, webpack, loader, vue-cli-3

In the vue-cli webpack chain, I want to change the compiled css source code. For example, I need to change the url reference suffix of png in all the background in the css file to webp. I write a loader, and how do I add this loader

Continue processing with the loader I wrote after the css-loader processing

Comment: Post your webpack.config file.

Comment: //  vue.config.js No configuration
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
  },
  chainWebpack(config) {}
}